# Where are MEO satellites put at the end of their operational life?

Tags: artificial-satellite, end-of-life, medium-earth-orbit

At the end of their operational life, satellites on geostationary orbit and higher are put in a [graveyard orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graveyard_orbit) that is higher than their operational orbit. Satellites in [LEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Earth_orbit) are slowed down so that [atmospheric drag deorbit them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_decay). Basically, at the end of their operational life:

- satellites in high orbit are put in a higher orbit
- satellites in low orbit are put in a lower orbit

That way, risk of collision between retired satellites and operational ones is lowered.

What about satellites in [MEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_Earth_orbit)?

For example, some navigation satellites are now retired (e.g. most of the [GLONASS first gerenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GLONASS_satellites)). Where are they now? Are they in an orbit with a periapsis such that atmospheric drag is no longer negligible (such as satellites in LEO at the end of their operational life)? In a higher graveyard orbit (such as satellites in geosynchronous orbit)? Elsewhere? What about other satellites in MEO?

Answer (score 7):

This is an [active area of research](https://conference.sdo.esoc.esa.int/proceedings/sdc7/paper/758). As you noted, the main satellites that are in MEO are navigation satellites. The short is they have their own disposal orbits, a bit further beyond the current constellations. It seems that GPS satellites are disposed by raising their apogee by about 1800 km (The perigee seems to remain the same)

Comment: I've just asked [Why end-of-life GPS satellites given orbits that seemingly still intersect active satellite orbits but with a different period? Recipe for disaster?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/56145/12102) and quoted this answer.